# How to get feature importance of FB prophet?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am using FB Prophet to do time-series forecast. I added two features--discount and promotion, and add holiday effect. The model fits well. But I want to get the feature importance to check how much contribution of 2 features. It seems FB Prophet does not have the feature importance function like other machine learning models "model.feature_importances_".

In FB Prophet, I can get the "forecast" dataframe, which contains :
*trend

yhat_lower

yhat_upper

trend_lower
trend_upper
discount_x

discount_lower

discount_upper

extra_regressors_multiplicative
extra_regressors_multiplicative_lower

extra_regressors_multiplicative_upper

holidays    holidays_lower

holidays_upper

multiplicative_terms    multiplicative_terms_lower

multiplicative_terms_upper

promotion_x
promotion_lower
promotion_upper
promotion_Day

promotion_Day_lower
promotion_Day_upper
weekly

weekly_lower

weekly_upper

additive_terms

additive_terms_lower

additive_terms_upper

yhat

y*

In that case, how can I analyze the feature importance?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

You can receive coefficients with following lines:

```py
from prophet.utilities import regressor_coefficients
regressor_coef = regressor_coefficients(model)
regressor_coef[['regressor', 'regressor_mode', 'coef']].sort_values('coef')*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SHAP to get it. It will tell you what are the features and how much it is contributing on individual level as well.